# Undefined variable:title after changing my code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I had written this code before someone helped me change it to suit the new Laravel 8.

**Category Factory**

```
$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $title = $faker->sentence;

    return [
        'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
        'slug' => Str::slug($title),
    ];
});
```

**Category Seeder**

```
class CategorySeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Category::factory()->count(10)->create();
    }
}
```

**Category Migration**

```
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title");
            $table->string("slug", 191)->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

After changing and putting the code under Category Factory.

```
public function definition()
{   
    return [
        'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
        'slug' => Str::slug($title),
    ];
}
```

After running `php artisan db:seed`, the slug code above displays the following.

> Undefined variable: title

This is after completely deleting the line `'$title = $faker->sentence;'` at the beginning of the code and running it under function definition as shown above. Can someone who has enough experience with Laravel show me how to fix this error?

Comment: `$title` is undefined, change this line `'slug'=>Str::slug($title),` to `'slug'=>Str::slug($this->faker->sentence),` will solve your problem

Comment: Or define `$title = $this->faker->sentence;` before your `return [...]`, then do `return ['title' => $title, 'slug' => Str::slug($title)];`. Either way, voting to close this as a typo/syntax error.

Comment: This is basic PHP, `$title` is not defined and you have to solve that for it to work...

Comment: This is the first time I'm trying to build a project using php. I'm not familiar with the language

Comment: I'd expect the concept to be similar for a lot of languages... If you try to use a variable you haven't defined, unexpected things can happen 